# Does ASP.NET Membership Provide a Way to Access the aspnet_Profile Table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I would like to be able to retrieve a value of one of the concatenated string properties (PropertyNames column) for the logged in user.

I looked through the Membership class but could not find any way so far.

Any idea? And what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Using System.Web.Profile.

Found the [following link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1659264.aspx?Get%20all%20profile%20property%20values%20) helpful about extracting individual properties.

Also, the app was throwing the following error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Security.SqlProfileProvider'
```

A change was needed to be made in the Web.Config file

The [following link](http://danhounshell.com/blog/could-not-load-type-system-web-security-sqlprofileprovider/) pointed to the main issue